# Multiple SPL Token Balance with one request

Tags: jsonrpc-api, api, java

To get the balance of a specific token from a wallet, I use `getTokenAccountsByOwner`, but this is giving the balance for only one token, and I need to request for more than one token.

I was wondering if it is possible to get the balance of multiple tokens for a wallet. Or if I can do it via websocket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should give all the tokens for a given owner assuming you use the programId filter and set it to TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID or TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, instead of using the mint filter.

edit:

to clarify, a couple methods get all tokens held for a given wallet address/any public key):

```
const tokenProgram = new PublicKey("TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA")

getTokenAccountsByOwner(pubkey, {programId: tokenProgram})
```

or:

```
import {TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID} from "@solana/spl-token"

getTokenAccountsByOwner(pubkey, {programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID})
```

and vice verse with the respective token 2022 program id

Comment: With that 2 values is not working, but I used `{"programId": "address_of_owner_program_of_the_tokens"}`